# How do I add icons to change view type in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, icons

Is there a way to add, in the nautilus tool-bar, or in the bottom of the window, icons to change visualisation mode? Icons, list, detail..

Comment: Posible? Yes, maybe.. available? no. The views can be changed with keyboard shortcuts which Nautilus indicates you, just learn them.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

The re-designed new nautilus (for complying with Gnome 3) has removed the toolbar feature from nautilus. So, there isn't anyway to add them except doing modification in nautilus code or with some patch.

But, there are nice shortcuts for those icons:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> for Icon view
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> for List View
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> for Details view

Hope this will help